# Magento new account email template customization

Tags: php, magento, email

I want customer email first part in the "new account" email template as per my requirement. For example: Dear . For example abc.xyz@something.com, then show 'Dear abc.xyz'

[image]

I found new account template in app/local/en_US/template/email/account_new.html file.

```
<h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>
```

Here I have changed {{htmlescape var=$customer.name}} to {{htmlescape var=$customer.email}} but i want only first part of email as "Dear " as welcome message.

How to split email in this template. As this is not a phtml file where do i need to change to get email first part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing, you should not modify the core files. Go to system > Trannsactional Emails. Load the email and edit the content there.

Comment: There we can edit as we need but how to get customer email first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of research I got a solution that can be solved programatically.

Modify the function sendNewAccountEmail in App/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php.

```
public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
    {
        $types = array(
            'registered'   => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled
            'confirmed'    => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
            'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // email with confirmation link
        );
        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
        }

        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
        }
        /* Updated code */
        $email_parts = explode('@', $this->getEmail());
        $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'email_firstpart' => $email_parts[0]), $storeId);
        /* End of updated code */

        return $this;
    }
```

I am sending email_firstpart to the Customer New Account email template. In order to make use this in that template, we have to use the following.

```
<h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear {{var email_firstpart}},</h1>
```

Comment: At least you should override it. It's not a good practice to hardcode the code.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this problem could be solved when we add custom template variables.

But how to create custom template variable in magento to get email first part.

[image]

Anyone please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I got a solution that can be solved programatically.

Modify the function sendNewAccountEmail in App/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php.

```
public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
    {
        $types = array(
            'registered'   => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled
            'confirmed'    => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled
            'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // email with confirmation link
        );
        if (!isset($types[$type])) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
        }

        if (!$storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
        }
        /* Updated code */
        $email_parts = explode('@', $this->getEmail());
        $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'email_firstpart' => $email_parts[0]), $storeId);
        /* End of updated code */

        return $this;
    }
```

I am sending email_firstpart to the Customer New Account email template. In order to make use this in that template, we have to use the following.

```
<h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Dear {{var email_firstpart}},</h1>
```

======>>>>> this is not working in my side so let me know any issue???

Comment: OK its working perfect!!   for a user email but what about admin email template.   i Want to edit admin mail template . so idea about that please give me solution